# JS function triggered by half-random id

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have many forms

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="my_id"> ... </form>
```

I have 1 form per element in my DB and i also have a JS function who send a SQL request based on the form i submit

```
$("#my_id").submit(function() { ... }
```

It does work for my 1st form only so i tried to change the id for each form like this

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="my_id<?php echo nb ?>"> ... </form>
```

where `nb`is an auto-incremented number. But the problem it doesn't enter in my function anymore (`for nb = 1, my_id != my_id1`).

How can i change my condition in the JS part? add wildcard?

```
$("#my_id*").submit(function() { ... }
```

Comment: `$(".className")` bundles all elements that have that class name ...

Comment: Use `$("[id*=my_id]").submit(function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
$("form[id^='my_id']")
```

This will select all form elements with ID starting with "my_id" .